# turn JSON to React components and vice versa

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Hi i'm new to react and i need to turn a JSON object into a react component and vice versa for them to be sent and stored into a Django back-end, the json objects will be later sent back from the back-end to be rendered. can this be done or is there a better way to do this?

here is an example of JSON object and it's equivalent react component

Json:

```
component: {
  name: 'Box',
  className: 'navbar',
  children: [
    { name: 'Button', classname: 'navbar-btn', children: ['Dashboard'] },
    { name: 'Button', classname: 'navbar-btn', children: ['Website Editor'] },
  ]
},
styles: [
  {
    navbar: {
      "display": 'flex',
      "position": 'fixed',
      'max-width': '225px',
      "height": '100vh',
      'background-color': 'darkslategray',
      "border": 'solid 1px grey'
    },
    'navbar-btn': { width: '225px' }
  }
]
```

equivalent react component:

```
<Box className="navbar1">
  <Button className="nav-btn">Website Editor</Button>
  <Button className="nav-btn">Dashboard</Button>
</Box>
```

css:

```
.navbar {
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    max-width: 225px;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color:darkslategray;
    border: solid 1px grey;
}

.navbar-btn {
    width: 225px;
}
```

is there a better way to represent components as JSON objects and can i easily turn a component into one?

Comment: Nope, you've got the gist of it. Shameless plug, I wrote a ReactAST that lets you write composable components in JSON making heavy use of interpolation - https://github.com/zuze-lab/react-ast/ The documentation site hasn't been completed, but it's written entirely in ASTs - https://github.com/zuze-lab/react-ast/tree/main/documentation/src/asts

Comment: Looks like what I'm looking for, i really hope i don't write this functionality myself 

Comment: It's extremely well tested, I know it works very wel and is stablel, but the documentation needs to get cleaned up, and I'd like to do whatever I can in typescript as well (hard because it's very interpolation-based). If you're interested contributing, I'm happy to take PRs!